# C# WPF toolkit: How can I make a cell from a datagrid be editable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, cell

Take note of the code for this small WPF C# program made with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008:

**.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDatagridTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <WpfToolkit:DataGrid 
        x:Name="DataGrid_" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        RowHeaderWidth="17" RowHeight="25" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfDatagridTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            const int MAX = 10;

            for(int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
                DataGrid_.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
                {
                    Header = i
                });
            DataGrid_.Items.Add("");
        }
    }
}
```

---

This program simply shows a WPF toolkit datagrid with 10 columns with headers and an empty row.

There is problem that occurs when a certain cell of the empty row is selected and then clicked to be edited: the program crashes. A message box shows up in Visual Studio saying this: "There is no source code available for the current location." I would like to know how can I make a cell from a datagrid be editable?

---

Here is the exception and stacktrace:

> System.InvalidOperationException was
>   unhandled   Message="'EditItem' is not
>   allowed for this view."
>   Source="PresentationFramework"
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.System.ComponentModel.IEditableCollectionView.EditItem(Object
>   item)
>          at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.EditRowItem(Object
>   rowItem) in
>   C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataGrid\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\DataGrid.cs:line
>   3396
>          at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedBeginEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs
>   e) in
>   C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataGrid\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\DataGrid.cs:line
>   2208
>          at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedBeginEdit(Object
>   sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) in
>   C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataGrid\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\DataGrid.cs:line
>   2036
>          at System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object
>   sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(Object
>   sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e,
>   CommandBinding commandBinding)
>          at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(CommandBindingCollection
>   commandBindings, Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command,
>   Boolean execute)
>          at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand
>   command, Boolean execute)
>          at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object
>   sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(Object
>   sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object target)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate
>   handler, Object target)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs
>   routedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object
>   source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   reRaised)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs
>   args, Boolean trusted)
>          at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object
>   parameter, IInputElement target,
>   Boolean userInitiated)
>          at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.Execute(Object
>   parameter, IInputElement target)
>          at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.BeginEdit(RoutedEventArgs
>   editingEventArgs) in
>   C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataGrid\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\DataGrid.cs:line
>   3059
>          at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e) in
>   C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataGrid\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\DataGridCell.cs:line
>   748
>          at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(Object
>   sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) in
>   C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataGrid\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\DataGridCell.cs:line
>   726
>          at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate
>   handler, Object target)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs
>   routedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object
>   source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   reRaised)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs args,
>   RoutedEvent newEvent)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.CrackMouseButtonEventAndReRaiseEvent(DependencyObject
>   sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object
>   sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate
>   handler, Object target)
>          at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs
>   routedEventArgs)
>          at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object
>   source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   reRaised)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs
>   args, Boolean trusted)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs
>   input)
>          at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr
>   hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp,
>   RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
>   Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr
>   lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr
>   lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr
>   lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object
>   o)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate callback, Object
>   args, Boolean isSingleParameter,
>   Delegate catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate
>   method, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr
>   lParam)
>          at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&
>   msg)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
>          at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object
>   ignore)
>          at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window
>   window)
>          at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window
>   window)
>          at System.Windows.Application.Run()
>          at WpfDatagridTest.App.Main() in
>   C:\Users\Frank\Documents\Visual_Studio_2008\Projects\WpfDatagridTest\WpfDatagridTest\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line
>   0
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

Comment: 1.3 k views and no upvote lol :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your ItemsSource to *Binding*, but there is no DataContext so this binding is useless. Then you are generating the columns in the code-behind and filling them with temporary data. From what I understand about the DataGrid, editing is only supported if there is data that the grid is bound to. Otherwise, what data are you editing?

Furthermore, I believe there is a *IsReadOnly* property (check the DataGrid documentation), which needs to be set to false (but I think it is false by default).

Comment: I'm generating empty columns and giving those columns a header. The data I am editing is the empty cells.

Comment: Is it possible to bind the datagrid to a some sort of empty list that while you edit the datagrid cells it adds the text from that cell to the list?

Comment: Definitely. Create a new class that represents the data you are storing the datagrid. Then you could bind to an ObservableCollection of that data. Similar to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx

Comment: I've tried using the ItemsSource and an ArrayList. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: ArrayList will not provide automatic change notification like ObservableCollection. If you do not need any change notification then ArrayList should be ok. You could also implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your own ArrayList class.